# Supported Android devices - 0 devices - Play Store

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest

I try to upload my app and i get 0 supported devices.
This is my manifest permissions

```
....
    </application>


        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="true"/>


        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" android:required="true" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" android:required="true" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"  android:required="true" />

    </manifest>
```

and here is the google play warning
[image]

Comment: add dependencies also ...

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="true"/>
```

changed it to

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.location" android:required="true"/>
```

and see if it works.. if not then you need to remove all the permissions and then add them one by one to see which was creating the problem ,,